# Compiling autoconf results in an incorrect version reporting

Tags: makefile, autoconf, automake, autoreconf

I want to update from autoconf 2.62 to 2.69.

I downloaded the source and ran the following:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

These all complete successfully.

When I run `autoconf --version` I get the following:

```
autoconf --version
autoconf (GNU Autoconf) ?K??
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+/Autoconf: GNU GPL version 3 or later
<http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>, <http://gnu.org/licenses/exceptions.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by David J. MacKenzie and Akim Demaille.
```

The problem you see here is that the version reports as **?K??**.

Why could this be? My machine runs in the EBCDIC codepage and I am wondering if this could be associated. Is there a configure / make option I need to add.

This issues stops me compiling other software, as the configure scripts check the version autoconf reports and it ends up failing those checks.

-----UPDATE-------
I have run `make check` as requested and this is the output:

```
autoconf269: >make check
make  check-recursive
Making check in bin
Making check in .
Making check in lib
Making check in Autom4te
Making check in m4sugar
make  check-local
Making check in autoconf
make  check-local
Making check in autotest
make  check-local
Making check in autoscan
Making check in emacs
Making check in doc
make: Makefile: line 436: Warning -- FSUM9433 Duplicate entry [fdl.texi] in prerequisite list
Making check in tests
make  check-local
cd ../lib/autotest && make  autotest.m4f
`autotest.m4f' is up to date
autom4te_perllibdir='..'/lib                     AUTOM4TE_CFG='../lib/autom4te.cfg'         ../bin/autom4te  -B '..'/lib -B '..'/lib --language=autotest -I . -I . suite.at -o ./testsuite.tmp
m4:local.at:18: bad expression in eval (bad input): ((?+1+0) > (2+0)) - ((?+1+0) < (2+0))
autom4te: /workarea/tools/m4/bin/m4 failed with exit status: 1
FSUM8226 make: Error code 1 
FSUM8226 make: Error code 255 
FSUM8226 make: Error code 1 
FSUM8226 make: Error code 255
```

My eyes are drawn to : `m4:local.at:18: bad expression in eval (bad input): ((?+1+0) > (2+0)) - ((?+1+0) < (2+0))` -- any ideas why this may be considered a bad expression?

Comment: Did you try updating using the distro package manager? Updating your build chain is unlikely to work piecemeal like this.

Comment: This platform has no package manager!

Comment: Try `autoconf --version | grep \062\056\066\071 | tr '\062\056\066\071' '2.69'` (the octal escapes are `2.69` in ASCII). If it prints the correct version line, you may have EBCDIC issues. You can also try `grep AC_INIT configure.ac` in the toplevel autoconf-2.69 source directory to determine whether it prints `2.69` or not. I'm unaware of what issues you may face going forward with an autoconf that deals exclusively with ASCII, but this provides you some valuable info at least.

Comment: If you're working on z/OS or some such platform where an EBCDIC code page is the native execution character set, you should try finding some patches. Python devs rejected upstream EBCDIC patches at one point [(Issue 1298)](https://bugs.python.org/issue1298), so I wouldn't be surprised if autoconf is EBCDIC-incompatible as well, and I'd be just as unsurprised if you found no patches. Again, the EBCDIC issue, if there is one, may be completely unrelated, but it might help for all we know. `make check` seemed to have no issue with the numbers, but the `?` in its error output may be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

One possiblity: the autoconf you compiled installed into /usr/local while the preinstalled one is in /usr. /usr is first in PATH so the preinstalled one is used.

You can also check the version before running make install to ensure, that the new verson fixes your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, after make, if i go into the bin dir and run ./autoconf -V I also get a version report of ?K??. The Path only has 1 directory with my new autoconf in it.

Comment: autoconf is a shellscript, so you can open it in your text editor and manual fix the version number. But the question remains, what went wrong during the build

Comment: It looks like the version number is generated with some m4 magic. can you try to run "make check" from your autoconf distribution?

Comment: I have editted the question to include this new content output from make check - thanks @arved.